# Relationship between tangential and angular acceleration in 3D

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics

In 3D circular motion, $\vec v=\vec \omega \times \vec r$, then the tangential acceleration is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec a_t =\frac{d \vec v}{dt} & = & \frac{d}{dt}(\vec \omega \times \vec r)\\
             & = & \frac{d \vec \omega}{dt} \times \vec r + \vec \omega \times \frac{d \vec r}{dt}\\
&=& \vec \alpha\times \vec r + \vec \omega \times \frac{d\vec r}{dt}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\vec \alpha $ is the angular acceleration. So for $\vec a_t = \vec \alpha \times \vec r$ to be true: if and only if $ \vec \omega \times \frac{d \vec r}{dt} =0$ .

That doesn't make sense to me, because the directoin of $\omega $ or $ d\theta$ is perpendicular to the plane at which the object is circling, and also perpendicular to $\vec r$, and this term will not be 0.

I find a [page online](https://pressbooks.online.ucf.edu/phy2048tjb/chapter/10-1-rotational-variables/#CNX_UPhysics_10_01_Circle:%7E:text=is%20constant%2C-,the%20term,-%E2%86%92), and the author says it's because r=0, and I think they are wrong.

Comment: Your equation for the acceleration is not the tangential acceleration, it is the acceleration vector.  $~\overrightarrow{a}=a_{t}\widehat{e}_{t}+a_{r}\widehat{e}_{r}~$

Answer (score 0):

You calculated the net acceleration of the given particle.
$$\frac{d{\vec{v}}}{dt}=\vec{\alpha}×\vec{r}+\vec{\omega}×\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}$$
$${\vec{a}_{net}}=\vec{a}_{tangential}+\vec{a}_{centripetal}$$